# WCF service method returning MessageContract works but the service itself throws errors

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest, messagecontract

I have a requirement to create a **WCF restful service** containing couple of operation contracts, where one of the operation contract of type **GET** takes input parameter as a string ID and returns a MessgeContract(as I needed to modify the SOAP body structure, i used MessageContract).

Now, when I browse the service `http://appname/service1.svc` in browser, it throws exception, saying that service method cannot use primitive parameters and MessageContract return type together, but when I execute the service method as : `http://appname/service1.svc/Method1?ID=2`, it works, and gives me required output and does not throw any exception.
Should I still keep using it, as all my Operation Contract methods execute correctly without exception except the service, what shall I do to improve this.